# linux permission issue with Multi Language admin in Code Igniter

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, permissions, user-permissions

I have created an admin panel in to add new languages for the CI application...

This was required because the client need to put about 20 languages, he has provided all the text of pages which need to be in different languages and they are mostly informative texts which may change in future..

So, I created the admin panel to load a list of all existing directories from `Language directory` and a simple CRUD is there to create the new language php file.

All is working fine but the issue is that my `apache user` at the server is different from the `FTP user`, and I am unable to remove the file / folder from ftp. to do so I have a few things in mind:

1. CHMOD the new folder and language PHP file to 777 {though I do it to write but then change it to 755 after file is written}
2. Place the new language folder/file to somewhere else out of application folder so I can 777 it without any harm.. { looked for it but unable to find any help }
3. no idea what to do...

I already have set `777` to `language directory` to let the Apache user write in the directory

I have a solution to change the owner of the project from `ftp user to apache` but, then wont be able to access files from ftp so I asked my network guy to add the apache user to the same group so I can change the permission to 775 but he is not sure if it will work or not and is not changing the group for apache user.

Main concern right now is making `...application/language` and `...application/language/*/*` 777 is fine or not?

If there is any-other alternative to it please let me know I can change the entire process if its gona work

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Leaving at 777 will not be a problem. The hacker would still need FTP or write access anywhere on the server in order to edit any files. As long as you properly authenticate every action and use CSRF protection in CodeIgniter you will be fine.

Also, you may want to add the same index.html as is found in the other CodeIgniter directories stating "Direct access is not allowed".

I have used these methods many times and they accomplish what you need without exposing yourself to threats.